# change background image from parent with child data

Tags: reactjs

im doing a weather app, and i need to change the background-image when the weather change.

in the parent i get my coords, and pass the coords to my weatherApp.jsx

(parent)

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import WeatherApp from './components/WeatherApp'

function App() {

  const [coords, setCoords] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {

    const success = (pos) => {
      const location = {
        lat: pos.coords.latitude,
        lon: pos.coords.longitude
      }
      setCoords(location)
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success)
  }, [])

  console.log(coords);
  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <WeatherApp lon={coords?.lon} lat={coords?.lat}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

in the child i use axios to get my data form openweathermap, but i need to change the background image from App.jsx

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const WeatherApp = ({lon, lat}) => {

    const [weather, setWeather] = useState()
    const [temperature, setTemperature] = useState()
    const [isCeslsius, setIsCeslsius] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (lat) {
            const APIKey = "***"
            const URL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${APIKey}`
    
            axios.get(URL)
              .then(res => {
                setWeather(res.data)
                const temp = {
                  celsius: {
                    celsius_temp: `${Math.round(res.data.main.temp - 273.15)}°C`,
                    celsius_min: `${Math.round(res.data.main.temp_min - 273.15)}°C`,
                    celsius_max: `${Math.round(res.data.main.temp - 273.15)}°C`
                  },
                  farenheit: {
                    farenheit_temp: `${Math.round((res.data.main.temp - 273.15) * 9/5 + 32)}°F`,
                    farenheit_min: `${Math.round((res.data.main.temp_min - 273.15) * 9/5 + 32)}°F`,
                    farenheit_max: `${Math.round((res.data.main.temp_max - 273.15) * 9/5 + 32)}°F`
                  }
                }
                setTemperature(temp)
                // trying to change the background image depending on the weather description react
                if (weather.weather[0].description === "clear sky") {
                  let bgImg = {
                    backgrounImage: "url(../public/clear-sky.jpg)"
                  }
                }
              })
              .catch(err => console.log(err))
        }
    }, [lat, lon])
    
    
    console.log(weather);

    const changeTemperature = () => setIsCeslsius(!isCeslsius)
```

maybe i could just use one component but i know there is a way to pass information from child to parent i just dont know how to

Comment: Never expose your API keys!

Comment: where do you get your description from? can you provide the object example that you get from your API?

Comment: weather: Array(1)
0:
description: "clear sky"
icon: "01n"
id: 800
main: "Clear"

Comment: which specific element that you want to change the background image? the App div? can you provide the className of that div?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). You can do something like this.

App.jsx

```
const [bgImg, setBgImg] = useState('');


<div className="App" style={{backgroundImage: bgImg}}>
```

Pass setBgImage to child

```
  <WeatherApp setBgImg={setBgImg} lon={coords?.lon} lat={coords?.lat}/>
```

In WeatherApp.jsx

```
   let bgImg = "url(../public/clear-sky.jpg)";
   props.setBgImg(bgImg);
```

This should set the background image of parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use useState hook and initialize it with the default value in parent component. Then pass the setter function to the WeatherApp component as p props.

In parent component

```
const [bgImgUrl, setBgImgUrl] = useState('your default URL here');
```

Pass the props to the WeatherApp component

```
<WeatherApp lon={coords?.lon} lat={coords?.lat} setBgImgUrl={setBgImgUrl} />
```

Then in the weather App component, you use to write your function

```
....
         setTemperature(temp)
                    
         if (weather.weather[0].description === "clear sky") {
             let bgImg = {
                 backgrounImage: "url(../public/clear-sky.jpg)"
             }
             // update the state
             props.setBgImgUrl(bgImg)   
         }

....
```

Comment: thx, both yours and @kiranvj ideas were pretty handy